# I am not able to install any packages in R version 4.0.2

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R as it is very helpful in statistical analysis. I have no prior knowledge in Coding. After the introduction to R, I was trying to install the packages that are supposed to help in arranging the data like "pacman",  "dplyr" ,"tidyr" ,"stringr" ,"lubridate" , "httr" , "ggvis", " ggplot2","shiny","rio","rmarkdown" . I am not able to install any package in **R 4.0.2** .
what is the problem here ?
what should i do to solve?

Comment: Hi Flamelotus. What commands are you using to install the packages? Stack Overflow may not be the best place to get help if you have no knowledge of coding at all, since most answers here will require an understanding of basic concepts. Following an introductory tutorial or textbook might be more helpful.

Comment: This the command i am using  to install.packages("pacman"). I am going through tutorial available in Youtube . Could you Please  give me  some suggestions how I should proceed .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you using RStudio or just R? Are you using a Mac or Windows?  Are you getting error messages?  What happens?

Comment: I am using Rstudio and I am using windows. Yes I am getting the error messages :-
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘pacman’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'

Comment: This RStudio Community Forums thread might help you: https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository-try-disabling-secure-download-method-for-http/16578 Some people found that changing an RStudio setting fixed this type of error you're getting

Comment: Thank you very much @duckmayr . It solved my problem .